# Interface with constructor inside implement questoin

Tags: interface, typescript

All:

I am pretty new to TypeScript, when I read TypeScript Handbook from its official site, there is one example:

> Difference between static/instance side of class When working with
>   classes and interfaces, it helps to keep in mind that a class has two
>   types: the type of the static side and the type of the instance side.
>   You may notice that if you create an interface with a construct
>   signature and try to create a class that implements this interface you
>   get an error:

```
interface ClockInterface {
    new (hour: number, minute: number);
}

class Clock implements ClockInterface  {
    currentTime: Date;
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
}
```

> This is because when a class implements an interface, only the
>   instance side of the class is checked. Since the constructor sits in
>   the static side, it is not included in this check.
>
> Instead, you would need to work with the 'static' side of the class
>   directly. In this example, we work with the class directly:

```
interface ClockStatic {
    new (hour: number, minute: number);
}

class Clock  {
    currentTime: Date;
    constructor(h: number, m: number) { }
}

var cs: ClockStatic = Clock;
var newClock = new cs(7, 30);
```

I just can not make myself understand why the last part work:

```
var cs: ClockStatic = Clock;
var newClock = new cs(7, 30);
```

**I thought that cs is a variable which is going to refer to an object with ClockStatic Type, but why it can access a class name? And I thought Clock type is irrelevant to ClockStatic, why it can be given to cs?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that cs is a variable which is going to refer to an object with ClockStatic Type

This is 100% correct.

> but why it can access a class name?

There are not "class names" in TypeScript/JavaScript. A class is an object like any other. You can think of the declaration `class Clock` being similar to the declaration `var Clock: ClockStatic`.

> And I thought Clock type is irrelevant to ClockStatic

The *class* (other name: *constructor function*) `Clock` has a type that is compatible with `ClockStatic`. The *type* `Clock` refers to the type you get when you instantiate that class.

> why it can be given to cs?

The *class* `Clock` satisfies the requirements of `ClockStatic` because it has an appropriate construct signature.

Comment: Thanks, although this may take time for me to understand, but I guess it changes some of my concept misunderstanding. But what I do not quite understand now is "class Clock", if declaring a class is like define a variable with class body as that variable type structure, then that "Clock" is just a variable name without any actual object referred by it, how can it be given to another variable? Just like in JS: var a; var b; b = a; this makes me really hard to understand